# Can I press charges if a coworker says he wishes my death?

Tags: relationships

I have a toxic coworker.
A few days ago, he said he had 2 types of wishes : good ones and bad ones. Among those bad ones is that he wants me to die
Can I press charges for such a statement ?

Comment: We really can’t give legal advice here, and of course the answers would depend on your (unspecified) location.

Comment: Then vote to close because this is asking for legal advice.

Comment: Yeah. The way it is presented it sounds stupid as in stupid joke - no law against wishes.

Comment: If you think he might be serious, go to the police. Do not just go to your employer. Even if he doesn't get arrested, at least the situation will have been documented, should something happen to you, or should you need to take further action. In any case, keep yourself safe and protected. Quit your job if you have to. No job is worth losing your life over.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did he say this privately, or were there witnesses?

Answer (score 9):

Do you believe he was voicing a serious threat?

yes? Lawyer up. You want proper legal advice for your jurisdiction. FAST.

no? if you believe he voiced himself in a highly inappropriate manner, but isnt serious about the threat, involve HR. This is highly inappropriate behaviour for any workplace.

Anyway: Document everything. Date and time when this happened. Every occasion he does something out of the ordinary, etc... This makes things easier for you when HR or law gets involved.

Last but not least: Listen to foreza's advice: Take care for yourself.

Comment: The OP did not say or imply that the co-worker made a threat.  The OP said that the co-worker said that the co wishes the OP was dead.  While reading fiction I frequently wish characters would die, that makes me neither a writer or a killer. I imagine there are a lot of people that wish Dennis Rader (BTK killer) was dead, I also image that zero of them are going to break into the jail to murder him.

Comment: OP didnt say if he believed his coworker or not. So included both possibilities.

Comment: My point was that seriously wishing for someone’s death may not be a crime (depending upon jurisdiction).

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer to improve clarity. My point was: Is this a threat, yes or no? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6):

Uh, that isn't good.

TO answer your first question - talk to your HR. Don't walk, run. 
Mention that your coworker 'X' has made a death threat.
You want this instance documented IMMEDIATELY.

Next - be prepared to provide additional information. You might need to divulge things like how long have you known your coworker,  any recent interactions, etc. You may be interviewed.

Finally, please be careful. A threat like this indicates a symptom of a deeper problem. Make sure you're not followed. Maintain a higher state of alert. Make sure you're not alone with this person.

Stay safe out there. Pressing charges is the least of your worries. Take care of yourself first.